# pyspark - java.sql.BatchUpdateException

Tags: pyspark, jdbc

Is it possible to check the (not null) constraints ion the target database table before writing the data into the target database table?

Is there anyway to handle the below exception in pyspark?

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 4 INSERT INTO public.empl ("id","name") VALUES (5,NULL) was aborted: ERROR: null value in column "name" of relation "empl" violates not-null constraint

I want to write data into a table via pyspark. But, I'm getting not null constraint error. I need to handle it without termination

Comment: provide your code that produce this error